# I was trying to read 3 vales each of char, float and int into three arrays, but It was not taking properly

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()  
{  
    char name[3];  
    float price[3];  
    int pages[3];  
    int i;  
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)  
    {
        printf("enter the title, price and pages of three books\n");  
        fflush(stdin);  
        scanf("%c %f %d", &name[i], &price[i], &pages[i]);  
        printf("the value of i is %d\n", i);  
    }  

   for(i=0; i<3; i++)
   {
       printf("the title of the book is %c, price of the book is %f,   
       number of pages of the book is %d", name[i], price[i], pages[i]);  
   }  

   return 0;  
}
```

The ouput I was getting was:

```
the title of the book is a, price of the book is 122.000000, number of pages of the book is 22
the title of the book is , price of the book is 0.000000, number of pages of the book is 134520820
the title of the book is b, price of the book is 0.000000, number of pages of the book is -10
```

What I want to get is:

```
the title of the book is Harry Potter, price of the book is 20, number of pages of the book is 22

the title of the book is 50 shades of grey, price of the book is 30, number of pages of the book is 60

the title of the book is Game of Thrones, price of the book is 40, number of pages of the book is 200
```

Comment: please add your input values and the expected outcome

Comment: what do you obtain if you write `printf("the title of the book is %c, price of the book is %f, number of pags of the book is %d", name[i], price[i], pages[i]);` as the last instruction of your first loop?

Comment: You question is incomplete. Tell us what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following changes , you will not get error.

```
for(i=0; i<3; i++)  
    {
       printf("enter the title, price and pages of three books");
       scanf("%c",&name[i]);
       scanf("%f",&price[i]);    
       scanf("%d",&pages[i]);
     }
```

Rest of your code is okay!

Answer (score 2):

Do the following changes to your code.

1. Change `char name[3];` into `char name[3][100];` for holding up to 100 char per entry.
2. Do not do `fflush(stdin);` . Because it is **undefined behaviour**.
3. scanf("**%s** %f %d", name[i], &price[i], &pages[i]);
4. use `%s` instead of `%c` in printf() too. **%c is used only for single char.**

Comment: Note: %s will ignore characters after first space. SO in the above exaple he can get only harry.

Comment: sorry for the incomplete information about my problem, I want my program to take the input as: single character for each book (i.e., for three books the title should be like A, B and c respectively,  and 3 float values for price and 3 int values for pages respectively with the same format specifiers. The problem with my program is: in the first iteration it is taking inputs like A 22.3 20 correctly, but in the second iteration, it is only taking title (i.e., B) and its not taking price and pages. after 2nd iteration it is directly printing all the values.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your scanf line with this and run it again,it will run fine and observe the difference
    scanf("%s%f%d",&name[i],&price[i],&pages[i]);